# Positioning blocks of PlantUML diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, plantuml, state-diagram, component-diagram

I'm trying to repeat a diagram using PlantUML. The diagram is like this:

[image]

I got stuck at trying to add more connections and make them look decent.

I started with object digram and came to something like this [link to online diagram](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/TP4nKeGm58Rxd28Nu0exUmSB2sQBIBBA2861E8pTWew5MpbZPMFX1N1THeHTlC9xD_8dweoDDEIzztr_GbYMJXNkAar4UHdRN1KgbL6MvfarrfsuwyJ8maHEsVF4217ICutKSiEtDF663jIkf2fbdc3qG2szqqGxtb8diNZbU-fe0Btrr5a6wX6j4SDFw1FrC7PuxxdcPbvvqCtWYqTQD4SeHw08zHRVKGU-nl10lJUgjGXFOwkpgWneWD7F3ZVVmzX6oN-9U-m-y0sIlF0dKwTmdZ0-peVZ3Q010BvRSetscxyAh13O-hWFxoajXDzI1dWMg7zB5BYfQYs3y2BMsjZLukTmGYoDrVWDNm00).

As soon as I start adding more connections, blocks break into chaos.

Then I tried component diagram. I started from [this diagram](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/VL6zRXD14ExlAPOqL4P2WZOAl48YKK_kvixBxSzfTmzZ8IJ780fI8L7HKF029iHAS1pp2hDlnAnDdBKiqgn6Ez_Fp3T7Fe0BlLR5K5OeK7TXB2hqfPDTaDOKZnzr3XeDGi7Oza6WQWlVIjE10oqSbW5Ce_2bTHMwaw4iMuFUYwSPgC8QUXLEy6rueMHZD9eWIdxGPIWbQrJIu75m4B0P2s-Lh3A0jiQMGsSrYk1wB8hZm41nG5zeHbUqeejuJdD1IoulumUweUi30LwSWaVnxXx-dJkpE8qVQHKdZ9wjKPs2K5kd_wFAnS_ucUQqOERvLjUUlkO4_9RqW_x42HClw8QnjtJDrFJ5Lfze7i_Y6JUN_mORMTVMoeuUPb-ozOBNMQQlECtubItxbAK60mscQglqZKctR3UD4wRop6bNmUuh-fNMJnNRpDOclzTgq7NElW75n-SReTjgVQKvKrQRDHX-nKHEEAcdIZnxydmj4A15MzUon3lgAsagE_83MgHZRERVRBvfb4gceTyNnLtwOZ0O7ER9vft3-yJotynuLsVN9kznSo-zFSH-8aTegbwhlm00) and got to something like this in trying to add one more blocks and connections: [link to online diagram](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ZL7DRjD04BxxAPPUE1a92MweAhn2At403bjxd2nPxrhhDI52I4tvET0J4YSk2F42RcbeIK9uXV4RCHitxYQR0XTxjFFDDz_tpLvfkR5LBgE-I851NjWHIw5CZ2Yiq2gwVQiml9Tp9lb8LvQ174JbGAY26vup0udbgYVXaJOfc8E-I0OAofBTzK0fPBoIzW1UseTIz5GEohA4Fc0yb1GPIA5WtnfkeJTYfPOYzG2vLZhf6vq3iwQ2ADgt16Gx-15hlC05dZKdE64uf_AyUOCplDnXl6I7l0JswXh-XJfrSzoynKLpHEXwYIeajvas-GsiL9ms7t22KveywNZruNDAeEo6lk5lugpn36U4_OMNRfIUQDLxd3JZPapD-PMmeJQ3JEhXtwVFQVMKxCpTKtFipQSwgLoMELUy1wxgc3xZWi1Zqdf4ewJPUMMqVO7VdNrNqPfwkUJdaeqNXT4lkAJZqut0T5oVS48ZYzO6mIzeq2LCxAvYz-xSNn9OFW2TPIA1rUXZeL8zB6ESkcEq-bldRIEHmXVz5MSazWUUOlrKCReFUMWFqBnZJW1EN3oK96dk4YIbhwDeTJxs88w9MiN-URnks-oY3pgUYv0pZZUKXuZWA5jHOTZH6Z6BOmcPfOMx8VH6PBXw4zj1_N2sy-twIMoZsRqECVBeoEIJlaXJKC-gOciSuPCtqnuXyBpvyEyjNkeUDBnlYEXiRU_7VdZUcdKBL_60-G-xAsJxesuRS1X3Y5YJ4ks1IgjS_W40).

The result is not satisfactory. I would appreciate any help in trying to add one more block to the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always try to keep it simple, using `-->` (vertical) layout as much as possible. That is the optimal strategy for the GraphViz algorithm, which is the basis of PlantUML.

The result is different from your original, but I hope you find it readable:

```
@startuml
'hide empty description
'!pragma layout elk
skinparam rectangleBorderThickness 1
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center
skinparam lifelineStrategy solid
skinparam monochrome true
skinparam style strictuml
hide empty members
skinparam Linetype ortho

rectangle "Базовые модули" as base {

class "Базовые объекты" as baseobjects
class "Делопроизводство\n4.5" as takeoffice
class "Управление\nпроцессами" as workflow
class "Windows-клиент" as windowsclient

class "Управление\nдокументами" as documentmanagement
class "Конструктор\nсогласований" as approvaldesigner

class "Платформа" as platform
class "Служба\n фоновых операций" as worker

}

platform <-- baseobjects
platform <-- workflow
platform <-- takeoffice
platform <-- windowsclient
platform <-- documentmanagement
platform <-- approvaldesigner

windowsclient -up-> approvaldesigner
windowsclient -up-> documentmanagement
windowsclient -up-> baseobjects
windowsclient -up-> takeoffice
windowsclient -up-> workflow

worker <-- approvaldesigner
worker <-- baseobjects
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is much more readable than what I managed to do. I tried to use longer arrows to manipulate the space between blocks, whcih didn't work out well.